# PhoneGap Application Performance evaluation

Tags: javascript, android, performance, cordova

I want to evaluate the performance of my Phonegap based Android application. I want to detect the load time of my application. i.e. time from tap to my application icon to startup page of my application? similarly the time my app takes from one form to another etc.  How should i approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre), which exposes a full firebug style console on your computer while you're debugging on your phone. You could use that for some profiling and other general debugging tasks.

Comment: The link for Weinre that you've provided no longer works sadly.